# в yii2 не работает метод load()

Tags: php, yii2

пытаюсь прикрутить `dosamigos/DatePicker`, но не получается.

передаю get-параметры в модель поиска:

```
$data_provider = $search_model->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

массив данных успешно приходит как в контроллер, так и в модель.

```
class SearchModel extends ModelName {
//code
    public function rules {
        return [['created_at'], 'safe'];
    }

    public function search($params){        
//code
        $this->load($params);
//code
    }
}
```

однако после `$this->load` в модели поиска свойство `created_at` почему то пустует, хотя другие параметры записываются вполне успешно и $params['created_at'] тоже присутствует.

в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказывается надо было явно указывать имя класса в имени инпута:

```
            'filter' => DatePicker::widget([
                'name' => 'ImagesSearch[created_at]', //было просто 'created_at'
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy'
                ]
            ])
```